# libc++, Clang and LLVM on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, clang, llvm, libstdc++

I have installed http://sourceforge.net/projects/clangonwin/ on my Windows system. My questions are:

1. It seems that a STD library is missing. How do I install one?
2. How can I integrate this in VC++, Eclipse, CodeLite, or Code::Blocks?

Answer (score 3):

Quote from the project page:

> if you want to compile C + + and uses the Microsoft C + + STL, please use the CL diver modes, namely: - dirver-mode = cl and disable RTTI;".

That answers your question.  Best to interpret its accuracy for the way it reads, the unintentional hint of death by drowning is in fact appropriate.  [This page](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html) gives a very decent insight what more work needs to be done before it is close to usable.

Comment: Can you be more specific. I don't want to use 'Clang' with 'MSVC' bu instead with his own ["libc++"](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) on Windows and I asked for a detailed tutorial on how to make it so.